# Weblogic 10.3 can not be accessed after enableing Administrator port

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, ssl, weblogic

I was was following this blog to set up some SSL connection. [One-Way SSL with JAX-WS using JDeveloper 11gR1 and WLS 10.3.1](http://one-size-doesnt-fit-all.blogspot.com/2009/08/one-way-ssl-with-jax-ws-using.html)

One of the steps mentioned is to enable the **Administration port** from **weblogic** **console**. I did that and change the **Admin port**. But, after saving everything get missed up the **conclose** closed and the I could not run the application form **Jdeveloper** .

**The Error message is:**

```
User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has administration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration Port.
**** Authentication error while connecting to application server IntegratedWebLogicServer. Please check settings.
**** Failed to complete start-up of application server IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer is shutting down.  All applications currently running will be terminated and undeployed.]
[Forcing termination of IntegratedWebLogicServer]
taskkill /F /PID 7480
Process exited.
```

This blog: [SOA OIM integration and WebLogic administration port](http://oraclemva.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/soa-oim-integration-and-weblogic-administration-port/)
discuss this issue BUT under the assumption that I can access the **weblogic console**. But it is not happening for me.

I am using **Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7** and the **weblogic 10.3**

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by deleting the system files for jdeveloper. This action will re insinuate the weblogic server. This file is located in my case in the following path: `C:\Users\[UserName goes here]\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper`.

Check this thread form Oracle community for more information : [Authentication error while connecting to application server IntegratedWebL](https://community.oracle.com/message/9546585#9546585)